# Visualizing the relationship of many categorical variables having same levels

Tags: r, visualization

I'm looking for a way to plot the relationship between many categorical features (like 20), which have the same levels. Here is a sample of my dataset - with only four columns for the example :

```
data.frame(plane = c("happy", "unhappy", "neutral", "neutral", "unhappy"),
           train = c("happy", "unhappy", "happy", "neutral", "unhappy"),
           car = c("happy", "happy", "neutral", "happy", "happy"),
           bike = c("unhappy", "happy", "unhappy", "neutral", "happy"))

    plane   train     car    bike
1   happy   happy   happy unhappy
2 unhappy unhappy   happy   happy
3 neutral   happy neutral unhappy
4 neutral neutral   happy neutral
5 unhappy unhappy   happy   happy
```

What are the options to plot the association or relationship between many categortical features ? I would like to avoid component analysis.

Comment: It's hard to show all 20 at once, but a `mosaicplot()` is good to compare small subsets.  If all you want is pairwise comparisons, you can put them in a matrix with `pairs()`.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly typical way would be to use a stacked bar plot. Just pivot your data into long format first.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = name, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", width = 0.5, color = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous("Percentage in each category", labels = scales::percent,
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d("Feeling", option = 5, direction = -1) +
  labs(y = NULL, title = "Feelings associated with different transport types") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

If you want a correlation-style plot, you could calculate percentage agreement as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

within(expand.grid(x = names(df), y = names(df)), 
       agree <- unlist(
         Map(function(x, y) {sum(df[x] == df[y])/nrow(df)}, x, y))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = agree)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black", linewidth = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(agree), color = agree > 0.5),
            size = 5) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_gradient("Agreement", low = "white", high = "deepskyblue4",
                      limits = c(0, 1), labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "white"), guide = "none") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: barplot doesn't show relationship between pairs of variables

Comment: @Kamaloka it depends what you mean by "relationship". This clearly shows how the distribution of levels in each column relate to the mode of transport. Can you clarify what you mean? Is it just whether the values in paired columns agree?

Comment: if features were numerical, I would do a correlation matrix. I would like to show whether observations tend to the same levels - e.g. does people being happy when taking the train are also happy when taking the plane

Comment: @Kamaloka see my edit. Is that what you mean?

Comment: King of, but levels cannot be indentified

Comment: @Kamaloka I know you keep trying to edit the question to replace `Map` with `purrr::map2`, but this is `base::Map` I am using, not `purrr::map`. This is _not_ a syntax error or a mistake.

Comment: @AllanCameron  My bad!  I didn't know about `base::Map()`. I even searched for it on Google before editing but nothing turned up on page 1 and I just assumed that it must be a syntax error.  FWIW, the line I edited was `Map(function(x, y) {sum(df[x] == df[y])/nrow(df)}, x, y)))`, and my edit was `purrr::map2(x, y, function(x, y) {sum(df[x] == df[y])/nrow(df)})))`